# Server Side Validation in MVC2 (such as Unique Email Address)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

how to Server Side Validation in MVC2 (such as Unique Email Address)

Answer (score 0):

Scott Gu [blogged about this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx).
You do this by setting up attributes in your model class (check out Step 2 in the blog.)